# netbeans deployng web application; deleted package names comes out

Tags: netbeans, build, web-deployment

I've created a simple web application. During the developement, i've created some java packages, that is folders under the src/java folder. Then I've deleted them. 
When i perform "clean", the build folder is regularlly deleted with its content.
When i perform "build" the build folder is created again with the content it is supposed to have. 
But when i perform "deploy" to my tomcat built-in web server (6.0.32) suddently in the build directory (build\web\WEB-INF\classes) the deleted folders appears (ok, with no-content) again!

This happens just for those directories and not newly created ones.
Since I guess it is difficult reproduce this anomaly, i rather trying to find where the "old-data" cache is, and since so far i haven't found it, i'm asking you.